# How to update the featured image in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Currently i am updating a post and that post already has a featured image i need to update the image, or change that featured image. How can i do it in wordpress through coding?

```
 if(my_post has featuredimage)
  {
     Update the featured image.
  }
```

Comment: see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail and http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-featured-image-url/

Answer (score 0):

you can use `set_post_thumbnail( $post, $thumbnail_id );`

See [Documents](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail) for more information.